# Mutli line label on java 1.2

Tags: java, user-interface, label

I am working on a application that runs on esmertec jbed jvm which is equivalent to Java 1.2 (without swing classes).

We have requirement for some multi-line labels in our application. Does anyone know of any existing component that will do this?

I have a good idea of how to write one myself but if there is one available already I would rather use that to save a bit of time.

EDIT 
I've tried using html components in the text before and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML in JLabels. To use it, your text has to start with .

Set your text to "This is
a multi-line string" and it should work.

See [Swing Tutorial: JLabel](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JLabel.html) and [Multiline label (HTML)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/MultilinelabelHTML.htm) for more information.

Comment: I can't use swing classes as they are not included in the JVM I am using

Comment: @Greg which label control do you have available?

Comment: Its just plain old Java 1.2 Label. I've tried adding html elements in it before and it does not work. I was hoping more to find a component that someone had written before.